# Have two (or more) divs with display: table-cell fill the entire screen, irrespective of the content in them using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want 2 divs, stacked on top of each other, with `display: table-cell;`.

I also want each div to have height and width as 100% of the screen.

I've already tried to do this, but I couldn't do it fully and here's my code.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.height {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.width {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.in-wrap {
  display: table-row;
}
.align {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="width wrapper">
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="align black">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h3>
      <p>
        <button>consectetur adipiscing elit</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="align">
      <h3>Donec auctor ornare augue vel lobortis.</h3>
      <p>Nulla pellentesque urna vitae felis congue aliquet.</p>
      <button id="projects">Nullam vitae pharetra nisl.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try display:block for your .wrapper class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `.in-wrap` a height of `100vh` and get rid of all of the `height: 100%`'s

```
.in-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: table-row;
}
```

Example....

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.width {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.in-wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  display: table-row;
}
.align {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.black {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="width wrapper">
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="align black">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</h3>
      <p>
        <button>consectetur adipiscing elit</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="in-wrap">
    <div class="align crisscross">
      <h3>Donec auctor ornare augue vel lobortis.</h3>
      <p>Nulla pellentesque urna vitae felis congue aliquet.</p>
      <button id="projects">Nullam vitae pharetra nisl.</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```